# Can I associate Visual Studio Code snippets with specific file types?

Tags: xml, visual-studio-code, dita

I want to create code snippets in Visual Studio Code for DITA, an XML data model. I had originally tried the below in my `dita.code-snippets` file but `dita` was not a recognized language.

```
{ 
    "template": {
        "scope": "dita",
         ...
    }
}
```

When I create a DITA file, Visual Studio Code correctly identifies it as XML so I changed the scope to `"scope": "xml"` and is was able to leverage the snippets. However...

I'd prefer that these snippets *only* show up for *.dita files and not for the broader class of *.xml files. Is this possible and (if so) how?